# How to derandomize the Chernoff bound?

Tags: derandomization, chernoff-bound

Avi Wigderson have a paper on how to derandomize the matrix-valued Chernoff bound. I would like to know whether there exists a simple version of paper on how to derandomize the real-valued Chernoff bound. Thanks so much!

Comment: In this answer I essentially sketch a derandomization of a typical application of Chernoff + union bound: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/19380/4896. See also the Chazelle book referenced there, and Section 3.5. in the multiplicative weights survey http://www.satyenkale.com/papers/mw-survey.pdf

Comment: What is the reference for Wigderson's paper? I doubt your reference is correct (or full).

Comment: I think it is correct reference. And now I know how to use it to get the result I want. Thanks!

Comment: Here's another worked example (derandomizing a Chernoff-bound based randomized rounding scheme for multicommodity flow): [http://greedyalgs.info/blog/intro/multicommodity-flow-slow/](http://greedyalgs.info/blog/intro/multicommodity-flow-slow/)

Comment: Updated URL for comment above: https://algnotes.info/on/obliv/lagrangian/multicommodity-flow-slow/